# In AWS EC2, is there a way to allow access only to a designated device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, server

I am new to AWS EC2. I want to set up a website only for my family members.
It will contain some content that is not necessarily private, but would be more appropriate if only family members can access.
IP address discrimination wouldn't work here as we may on the go and use other wifi.
I'm considering MAC code as the screening basis.
Is such access restriction allowed in EC2? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply add a login page?

Comment: @SAUJ I've heard it's vulnerable to attacks. Isn't it true?

Answer (score 0):

Restricting is using MAC won't work, the devices will reach EC2 over a public Network and the MAC changes at every hop. I assume you would be interested in setting remote vpn/L2TP vpn ? EC2 can be used as VPN server and can be allowed from certain client, if no, try to setup a log in based page and create account for your family members.
Here a free open source tool to achieve it:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-sync-and-share-your-files-with-seafile-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thank you for your generous guide. Could you please point out some basic tutorials for implementing logins. My backend is Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) is designed for such things, you can manage there user accounts. You can add `Application Load Balancer` before your `EC2` instance, which will forward to `Cognito` authentication - but this is a bit expensive solution for "family usage".

If there's no very fragile data on this website, you can use just [BasicAuth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), which will prompt for username and password on site-entry, or you can add standard login page in your website.

Least, but not last, is `Lambda` with `ApiGateway` (free tier allows to free usage of this service for ALOT of requests) - this is more programatically solution - but - it's up to you which one to choose.

Comment: Thank you. Which one of the three is most newbie-friendly?

Comment: @JinghuiNiu easiest will be standard `BasicAuth`

Comment: If I want more protection, is `Cognito` the next level up? Compared to `Lambda`?

Comment: @JinghuiNiu yes, Cognito will provide login system for your users, and don't allow traffic to unathourized users, but any service will provide security to your resources, remember that blocking resources from unathorized access is your responsibility. You have to secure this EC2 instance (put this EC2 instance in private network and allow access to it only from `Application Load Balancer`) - for example by `Security Group`